# Ошибка Connect timed out при инициализации проекта в IDEA

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, maven, gradle

Помогите с проблемой, IDEA перестала запускать проекты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Пытаюсь инициализировать его  - выходит такая ошибка.
То есть не билдятся нужные папки, от слова совсем. Пытался кучу всего - менял версии джавы, создавал проект с командной стркои(через градл) и через идею, отключал фаервол на винде, поставил все галочки в нем сначала, связанные с IDEA и java ,IDEA  точно в фаерволе добавлена актуальная, переустановка IDEA , делал проект на maven.. без изменений
Еще момент - я могу создать проект на винде и там он отлично собирается и работает. на WSL перестал. Хотя вчера еще все было ок.
Яв тупике

Comment: Это фатал, его нельзя исправить. Попробуй запускать из Maven. Хотя все равно работать не будет, если есть зависимость от ОС.